# Case sensitive join in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I am dealing with a scenario in which I need to write a case sensitive join condition. For that, I found there is a spark config property `spark.sql.caseSensitive` that can be altered. However, there is no impact on the final result set if I set this property to `True` or `False`.
In both ways, I am not getting results for `language=java` from the below sample `PySpark` code. Can anyone please help with how to handle this scenario?

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.caseSensitive", False)

columns1 = ["language","users_count"]
data1 = [("Java", "20000"), ("Python", "100000"), ("Scala", "3000")]

columns2 = ["language","note"]
data2 = [("java", "JVM based"), ("Python", "Indentation is imp"), ("Scala", "Derived from Java")]

df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data1, columns1)
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data2, columns2)

#df1.createOrReplaceTempView("df1")
#df2.createOrReplaceTempView("df2")

df = df1.join(df2, on="language", how="inner")
display(df)
```

Comment: Whats stopping you to add a consistent transform towards the join column - 

`df1.join(df2, F.lower(df1["language"]) == F.lower(df2["language"]), how="inner")`

Comment: Provided data is sample data. In the actual scenario, there are alphanumeric ids something like 123Abc & 123aBc.  These are different ids in my case. Looks like this case sensitive join is happening by default. However, now I am looking for a property using which I can alter this case sensitivity.

Answer (score 3):

1. My understanding of `spark.sql.caseSensitive` is that it affects SQL, not the data.
2. As for your join itself, if you do not want to lowercase or uppercase your data, which I can understand why, you can create a `key` column, which is the lowercase version of the value you want to join on. If you are having more complex situation, your `key` column could even become a `md5()` of one/more columns. Make sure everything stays lowercase/uppercase though to make the comparison works.

Comment: Agree. md5() would be a better approach in such a scenario.  However, is there any standard property available to alter join condition case sensitivity? something like "COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CS_AS" hint we can give in SQL Server joins.

Comment: I hate it when it comes to pesky collation like in French :). Collation should not impact your join, encoding could, but I am pretty sure Spark gets rid of the specific encoding if you ingest with the right code set.